# A simple method for a "master" thread to monitor "slave" threads

Tags: pthreads, posix

As my first real foray into using pthreads, I'm looking to adapt an already written app of mine to use threads.

The paradigm I have in mind is basically to have one "master" thread which iterates through a list of data items to be processed, launching a new thread for each, with MAX_THREADS threads running at any given time (until the number of remaining tasks is less than this), each of which perform the same task on a single data element within a list.

The master thread needs to be aware of whenever any thread has completed its task and returned (or pthread_exit()'ed), immediately launching a new thread to perform the next task in the list.

What I'm wondering about is what are people's preferred methods for working with such a design?   Data considerations aside, what would be the simplest set of pthreads functions to use to accomplish this?  Obviously, pthread_join() is out as a means for "checking up" on threads.

Early experiments have been using a struct, passed as the final argument to pthread_create(), which contains an element called "running" which the thread sets to true on startup and resets just before returning.  The master thread simply checks the current value of this struct element for each thread in a loop.

Here are the data the program uses for thread management:

```
typedef struct thread_args_struct  
{  
    char *data;         /* the data item the thread will be working on */
    int index;          /* thread's index in the array of threads */  
    int thread_id;      /* thread's actual integer id */  
    int running;        /* boolean status */  
    int retval;         /* value to pass back from thread on return */  
}   thread_args_t;  

/*  
 * array of threads (only used for thread creation here, not referenced  
 * otherwise)  
 */  
pthread_t       thread[MAX_THREADS];  

/*  
 * array of argument structs  
 *  
 * a pointer to the thread's argument struct will be passed to it on creation,  
 * and the thread will place its return value in the appropriate struct element  
 * before returning/exiting  
 */  
thread_args_t   thread_args[MAX_THREADS];
```

Does this seem like a sound design?  Is there a better, more standardized method for monitoring threads' running/exited status, a more "pthreads-y" way?  I'm looking to use the simplest, clearest, cleanest mechanism possible which won't lead to any unexpected complications.

Thanks for any feedback.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't so much a "pthreads-y" way as a (generic) multi-threading way.  There is nothing wrong with what you have but it is more complicated and inefficient than it need be.

A more standard design is to use a thread pool.  The master thread spawns a bunch of worker threads that read a queue.  The master puts work in the queue and all the workers take a shot at processing the work in the queue.  This eliminates the need to constantly start and terminate threads (though more sophisticated pools can have some mechanism to increase/decrease the pool size based on the work load).  If the threads have to return data or status information they can use an output queue (maybe just a pointer to the actual data) that the master can read.

This still leaves the issue of how to get rid of the threads when you are done processing.  Again, it is a master-worker relationship so it is advised that the master tell the slaves to shut themselves down.  This amounts to using some program switch (such as you currently have), employing a condition variable somewhere, sending a signal, or cancelling the thread.  There are a lot questions (and good answers) on this topic here.

Comment: Thanks, Duck,  Yes, I like that idea you suggested.  The only issue, though, is that I do need a certain amount of synchronization in the design as well.

Comment: (oops, hit enter too soon)  The master thread needs to wait for a certain group of slaves to all be finished, so it can use some information generated by them to create an output file.  I do think I need to give a lot more thought to the design.  It *would* be nice not to get too bogged down in thread management, but just have everything working more or less autonomously and cooperatively.  Will have to ponder this a bit.  Thanks very much.